# Need to display field labels in an alphabetical order

Tags: visualforce, describesobject, schema

I am displaying all the fields of an object in a picklist. I am fetching the same using the Schema.SObject class.
But, I want to display the labels in the picklist in an alphabetical order. Is there any method for fetching the labels that return them in an alphabetical order?

My code :

```
lstUnSelecetdLeadFields.add(new SelectOption(mapLeadFieldAPIToSchema.get(fieldAPI).getDescribe().getName(),mapLeadFieldAPIToSchema.get(fieldAPI).getDescribe().getLabel()));
```

Comment: No, that method does not exists out of the box, but you can use standard **sort** method on list of strings to sort them

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class with Comparable Interface which will allow you sorting based.
Eg -

```
global class Sample {     
public List<Student> StudList {get;set;}   

public Sample() {
    StudList = new List<Student>();
    Student s1 = new Student('Ganesh', 12);
    StudList.add(s1);

    Student s2 = new Student('Arun', 82);
    StudList.add(s2);

    Student s3 = new Student('Vignesh', 32);
    StudList.add(s3);

    Student s4 = new Student('Younis', 55);
    StudList.add(s4);     

    Student s5 = new Student('Azhar', 42);
    StudList.add(s3);   

    StudList.sort();
}

//wrapper class for Comparable Interface

global class Student implements Comparable {
    global String StudentName {get;set;}    
    global Integer StudentAge {get; set;}

    global Student(String Name, Integer Age) {
        StudentName = Name;
        StudentAge = Age;
    }

    global Integer compareTo(Object ObjToCompare) {
        return StudentName.CompareTo(((Student)ObjToCompare).StudentName);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) for your reference